# Why is this CW complex connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, connectedness, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups

I am working on Exercise 4.1.11 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* text, which is as follows:

> Show that a CW complex $X$ is contractible if it is the union of an increasing sequence of subcomplexes $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots$ such that each inclusion $X_i \hookrightarrow X_{i+1}$ is nullhomotopic.

By applying Whitehead's Theorem, if we show that $\pi_n(X,x_0) = 0$ for all $n$ and any point $x_0 \in X$ and that $X$ is connected, it will follow that $X$ is contractible.

It is already shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/x-a-cw-complex-is-contractible-if-its-the-union-of-an-increasing-sequence) that $\pi_n(X,x_0) = 0$ for all $n$ and any point $x_0 \in X$. What's not shown there, however, is that $X$ is connected.

How can we show that $X$ is connected?

Thanks!

Comment: Well it's the union of an *increasing* sequence of complexes, so any point in one of them is also in all later ones. That with fact each is connected gives what you want (I think).

Comment: @coffeemath How do we know that each of the subcomplexes is connected?

Comment: In the case $n=0$ triviality of $\pi_n(X,x_0)$ says that $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: @michiganbiker898: You do not need path-connectedness of each $X_n$ for the proof.

Comment: The link in the post ([current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4351251/1)) does not work. Maybe you wanted to link to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62533 ?

Comment: The link you reference is broken.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks! I fixed it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you! That's the one. I fixed the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that $\pi_0(X,x_0)=0$, then the result is trivial. Explicitly, you can consider two points $x,y$. There is an $i$ such that $x,y\in X_i$. Since the inclusion $X_i\to X_{i+1}$ is nullhomotopic, there is an arc connecting these two points in $X_{i+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! So, triviality of $\pi_0(X,x_0)$ for any point $x_0 \in X$ corresponds to path-connectedness (and hence connectedness) of $X$, right?

Comment: Aah, I see. What I said in the comment above is correct: the discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596822/zeroth-homotopy-group-what-exactly-is-it is helpful for this.